# How to interpret KPSS results?

Tags: r, stationarity, kpss-test

I'm using R to calculate the KPSS to check the stationarity.

The library that I'm using is *tseries* and the function is **kpss.test**

I have done a simple test using *cars* (a default matrix on R). The code is:

```
> k <- kpss.test(cars$dist, null="Trend")
Warning message:
In kpss.test(cars$dist, null = "Trend") :
  p-value greater than printed p-value
> k    
        KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  cars$dist 
KPSS Trend = 0.0859, Truncation lag parameter = 1, p-value = 0.1

> k$statistic
KPSS Trend 
0.08585069 

> k$parameter
Truncation lag parameter 
                       1 
> k$p.value
[1] 0.1

> k$method
[1] "KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity"

> k$data.name
[1] "cars$dist"
```

Those are all the results that kpss returns.

My question is: *How to interpret them to understand if it is stationary?*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You specified a null hypothesis of trend stationarity. That is the data follow a straight line time trend with stationary errors. The p-value is 0.1, so the null hypothesis is not rejected at the usual 5% level.

Comment: I could translate your answer as: IF p-value is ABOVE 0.05 the trend is stationary otherwise NOT, correct?

Comment: A trend cannot be stationary. The null hypothesis is a time trend with stationary errors, as I explained.

Comment: yes, excuse me: I meant a time trend with stationary errors. by the way, if the p-value is ABOVE 0.05 it means that is mean reverting (Stationary) right?

Comment: Assuming you are using the 5% level, then a p-value above 0.05 means you have no evidence that it is not trend stationary. That is not the same as saying that it is trend stationary.

Comment: perfect! I understand.... BELOW it i have evidence that it "maybe" trend stationary.

Comment: If the null hypot. is: trend stationarity and the p-value <0.05, than the null is rejected, i.e. the process is not trend stationary.

Comment: What is the difference between trend stationary and level stationary??

Comment: Trend stationary means "stationary around the trend", i.e. the trend needn't be stationary, but the de-trended data is. Level stationary means that the data is like white noise.